# Using OptaPlanner to solve VRP where customers have priorities: high, standard or low

Tags: optaplanner

I am using Optaplanner to solve my VRP problem, I have adjusted the VRP example of time windows and capacities to my requirements. In my problem I have a fleet of vehicles and a list of visits (customers), where each visit has a priority that can be High, Normal or Low.

A visit with High priority is a visit that must be visited on the route, it would never be outside and it would have priority over the visits with Normal and Low priority. Similarly, with Normal priority are those visits that should be part of the route but with less priority than those with High priority. And in the case of Low priority, the optimisation of the route would not be affected; those visits that are not important to consider, this would probably be the default value. I have searched for similar questions but without success.

1- What changes should I implement in my optaplanner domain and what restriction could you suggest to enforce this requirement related to customer priorities (visits)?

2- Should I implement a selector or can I make my constraints enforceable only with a constraint provider? I started using OptaPlanner a short time ago and the issue of selectors and moves is still very difficult for me to understand yet.

Thank you in advance. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To allow some visits to not be assigned, one trick is to create exactly one dummy vehicle and ignore all constraints for visits assigned to the dummy vehicle. Then use HardMediumSoftScore to medium penalize all unassigned visits.

As for dealing with high - normal - low: look at HardSoftMediumScore (or  BendableScore if you need more than 3 levels). You can have the hard level penalize all unassigned high visits, the medium (or bendable first soft) level penalize all unassigned normal visits, the soft (or bendable second soft) level penalize all unassigned low visits, etc.